# When i click on menu button it open menu but when i click close button its not closing it

Tags: javascript, html, menu

I was making a  menu
Button for a site , so when i click on menu , it change its innerhtml but when i click on close button its not changing its innerhtml.

Js code

```
function MENU() {
var MENUITEMS = document.getElementById('MENU')
MENUITEMS.innerHTML=" <a style='text-decoration:none;' href='OUR_WORKS.html'>OUR_WORKS</a><p class='LGND'>ABCD</p><button id='CLOSE'class='LGND' onclick='CLOSE()'>CLOSE_MENU</button>"
}
function CLOSE() {
var MENUITEMS = document.getElementById('MENU')
MENUITEMS.innerHTML="  <p onclick='MENU()' id='MENU'>MENU</p>"
}
```

Html code

```
 <p onclick="MENU()" id="MENU" 
 >MENU</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you click on the container `#MENU`,  it will show the menu. The problem is that **even when the menu is open**, clicking on `#MENU` will show the menu. So clicking the "close" button will close the menu, then open it again.

One way you could fix this is by storing the state of the menu in a variable - like this:

```js
var OPEN = false,
  MENU_ELEM = document.getElementById("MENU");

function TOGGLEMENU(){
  if(OPEN){
    //menu is open, we need to close it
    OPEN = false;
    MENU_ELEM.innerHTML = "<p onclick='TOGGLEMENU()'>MENU</p>";
  } else {
    //menu is closed, we need to open it
    OPEN = true;
    MENU_ELEM.innerHTML =  "<a style='text-decoration:none;' href='OUR_WORKS.html'>OUR_WORKS</a><p class='LGND'>ABCD</p><button id='CLOSE'class='LGND' onclick='TOGGLEMENU()'>CLOSE_MENU</button>";
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="MENU"><p onclick="TOGGLEMENU()">Menu</p></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

**See the example below.**

A few suggestions:

- `p` tag is not meant for a button. Use `button` element instead.
- Swapping out `innerHTML` purely via JavaScript interferes with accessibility. Consider using static HTML markup and CSS styling to achieve the effect.

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('button');
const menu = document.querySelector('ul');

btn.addEventListener('click', toggle);

function toggle() {
  menu.classList.toggle('active');
  btn.classList.toggle('active');
}
```

```css
ul {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateX(-20px);
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: opacity .2s, transform .2s;
}
ul.active {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateX(0);
  pointer-events: all;
}

button.active::after {
  content: ' X';
}
```

```html
<button>MENU</button>
<ul>
  <li>
    <h2>Our Works</h2>
  </li>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
  <li>Item 5</li>
  <li>Item 6</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution :-

HTML :-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css">
  <script src="js/index.js"></script>
  <title>SITE</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="Menu"><button onclick="Menu();" id="Imenu" >MENU</button></div>
</body>
</html>
```

JS :-

```
//Menu opening


function Menu() {
 var btn=document.getElementById("Menu");
 btn.innerHTML="<button onclick='oldstagemenu();' id='Imenu' ><a href='your-File.html'>OUR WORKS</a> | <a href='your-File.html'>ABOUT US</a> | <a href='Your-File.html'>CONTACT-US</a> | CLOSE-MENU❌</button>"
 
}

//Menu closing


function oldstagemenu() {
 var btn=document.getElementById("Menu");
 btn.innerHTML="<button onclick='Menu();' id='Imenu' >MENU</button>"
 
}
```

Just change the onclick function from open to close menu.